# Understanding apply and groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I'm trying to understand an example from Python for Data Analysis book by Wes McKinney. I've looked through the pandas cookbook, documentation and SO but can't find an example like this one.

The example looks at the 2012 Federal Election Commission Database (https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/master/ch09.ipynb). The code below determines the top donor occupations donating to Obama and Romney.

I'm struggling to understand how the function takes a groupby object and performs another groupby operation on it. When I run this outside of the function I get an error. Could somebody shed some light on this behaviour?

Thanks,

Iwan

```
# top donor occupations donating to Obama or Romney
def get_top_amounts(group, key, n = 5):
    totals = group.groupby(key)['contb_receipt_amt'].sum()

    return totals.sort_values(ascending  = False)[:n]

# first group by candidate
grouped = fec_mrbo.groupby('cand_nm')

# for each group, group again by contb_receipt_amt so we have a hierarchical index
# take the contribution amount
# then return the total amount for each occupation by cand sorted to give top n
grouped.apply(get_top_amounts, 'contbr_occupation', n= 5)
```

The result looks like this

```
cand_nm        contbr_occupation                     
Obama, Barack  RETIRED                                   25270507.23
               ATTORNEY                                  11126932.97
               INFORMATION REQUESTED                      4849801.96
               HOMEMAKER                                  4243394.30
               PHYSICIAN                                  3732387.44
               LAWYER                                     3159391.87
               CONSULTANT                                 2459812.71
Romney, Mitt   RETIRED                                   11266949.23
               INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS    11173374.84
               HOMEMAKER                                  8037250.86
               ATTORNEY                                   5302578.82
               PRESIDENT                                  2403439.77
               EXECUTIVE                                  2230653.79
               C.E.O.                                     1893931.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `apply` on a grouped dataframe you are actually iterating over the groups and pass each group the function, you're applying. 
Let's look at a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'col2': ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b'],
                   'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
grouped = df.groupby('col1')
```

Now let's create a simple function which allows us to see what's getting passed to the function:

```
def print_group(group):
    print(group)
    print('=' * 10)

grouped.apply(print_group)
   col1 col2  value
0     1    a      1
1     1    b      2
2     1    a      3
3     1    b      4
==========
   col1 col2  value
0     1    a      1
1     1    b      2
2     1    a      3
3     1    b      4
==========
   col1 col2  value
4     2    a      5
5     2    b      6
6     2    a      7
7     2    b      8
==========
```

As you can see each group is getting passed to the function as a separate dataframe. And of course you can apply all the normal functions to this subset.
The fact that you see the first group twice is due to internal reasons and cannot be changed, it's not a bug ;).

Let's create another function to proof this:

```
def second_group_sum(group):
    res = group.groupby('col2').value.sum()
    print(res)
    print('=' * 10)
    return res

grouped.apply(second_group_sum)
col2
a    4
b    6
Name: value, dtype: int64
==========
col2
a    4
b    6
Name: value, dtype: int64
==========
col2
a    12
b    14
Name: value, dtype: int64
==========
```

You could even go further and do group-apply-group-apply-group-apply etc etc...

I hope this helps a bit understand what's going on.

By the way if you use ipdb (debugging tool) you can set a breakpoint in the applied function a interact with the group dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Jan! So to make sure I got this.

The grouped variable, defined above, is a DataFrameGroupBy object. But when acted upon by the apply function, it behaves like a DataFrame. This is what allows to perform a secondary group by as you did in second_group_sum.

Comment: Yes, `grouped` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object. And what it does, when you use `apply(function)` is pretty much splitting the underlying DataFrame into multiple DataFrames, one for each group.